# windowbuilder textfield not working with combobox

Tags: java, combobox, textfield, windowbuilder

I have a problem where I have a comboBox that causes an action that sets the text in a textField.  Here's the code:

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   private JPanel contentPane;
   private JTextField textField;
   private JComboBox comboBox;

   //public static void main - nothing much in it except Main frame = new Main();

   public Main() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 563, 407);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    comboBox.addActionListener(frame);
    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(42, 99, 445, 235);
    textField.setText("HERE");
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
    comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Bob", "Dan ", "Emily"}));
    comboBox.setBounds(42, 48, 140, 29);
    contentPane.add(comboBox);

    /*ONE WAY OF DOING IT: comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        textField.setText(studentOutputString((String)comboBox.getSelectedItem()));
        textField.setText("BLAH");
    }
});*/
}
    public String studentOutputString(String student){
        String s = student + "is printed.";
        return s;
}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        String selectedStudent = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        textField.setText(studentOutputString(selectedStudent));
}
```

Nothing shows up in the textField.  Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

I reformatted it and caught up on my past threads.

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Dave - noted.  Plus, I chose answers to some questions that were unanswered.  Hadn't seen some of the posts before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate an action on the ComboBox in order for the action listener to be called and set the text of the TextField.  Try selecting an item in the ComboBox

Also, `comboBox.getSelectedItem()` might return null if there are other events besides change of selected items (e.g. an event is generated before a selection was made).  In that case your call to `student + "is printed."` inside `studentOutputString()` will throw a null-pointer exception

Comment: I have tried changing the values in the combobox to no avail.  I do not know what to do.

Comment: not _changing_ the values in the combobox, but _selecting_ and item in the combobox when the application is running.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the first line of the `actionPerformed()` method and run the program under the debugger.  See if the breakpoint is ever hit when you are selecting an item in the combobox.  If it does break, see what happens (how the variables change) as you step through that method.